# How to rename every URL on a column to share the same name in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I have 10 youtube link & 700 stackoverlow link on the same column A. What to do to make that entire column all have the name 'My Link'. So on an empty cell, when I paste a link/url it automatically names itself 'My Link'.

I have tried searching for the result couple of time and stumbled upon =HYPERLINK(A1, "RECEIPT") & =ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(F1:F500, "RECEIPT")). I do not wish to to create a seperate colume where it says 'My Link' while another colume to paste the links on. I tried =HYPERLINK($A1, "My Link") and dragged down to copy the formula on the cell below but that gave Error because my links started from A2. Once I change it to =HYPERLINK($A2, "My Link") it works but every url moves up 1 cell above which doesnt properly reflect the corresping cell data. Not sure if my explanation was understandable or not.

Again I need the formula to impact the entire column A with the URLs without relying on a transfer to a different column. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change what's in the column without using a helper column would be to use a script, which is probably overkill.

If you are OK with using a temporary helper column you could do it like this:

1. In cell `B1`, put the formula `="=HYPERLINK("""&A1&""", ""My Link"")"`
2. Copy this formula down to the end of your URLs (grab the small black box in the bottom right corner and drag down)
3. Select all the cells in column `B` and copy (ctrl/cmd + c, or right-click and 'copy')
4. Right-click in cell `A1` and choose 'Paste Special' -> 'Paste values only'
5. Select column `A` (by clicking the 'A' at the top), then on the menu bar choose 'Format' -> 'Automatic'
6. You can then delete everything in column `B`

*Edit*: if you are OK with using a helper column, this would be much easier.

1. URLS in column `A`
2. `=HYPERLINK(A1, "My Link")` in `B1` and copy down.
3. Hide column `A`

Comment: thank you for the comment, I did try it out but not really what I was looking for as I would have to keep doing it when I want to add a new URL and repeat the process.

Comment: Your question didn't mention adding to the list of URLs. If that's what you are doing, the simplest solution is just to use a helper column (with the URLs in it), then use `HYPERLINK()` to get the links you want. You can always hide the helper column.